# Connecting to Python Using Specified Credentials Using pyodbc or pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, pyodbc

At work we use SQL Server table to store a wide variety of information. Recently I created GUI that allows users to submit data to a SQL table. Rather than giving the user access to our tables, we'd like to specify the user credentials in our code. I found one Python script specifying the user credentials, but I still receive an error when attempting to force Python to use those credentials.

Below is the code I've used to connect to SQL Server (I've left out some info just for security purposes). The code works for both my querying and inserting values, but I believe uses my windows authentication. Following are the problems I experience when tring to specify credentials:

1. When adding in a line for UID, PWD, and removing the Trusted_Connection portion, I still encounter a login failed error.
2. The SQL Server user name contains a '' which is replaced by '\' when I see the login failed error. Ex: username = Ryan\B23456 the terminal displays Ryan\B23456. Is that part of my problem?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server};"
    "Server=;"
    "Database=;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Your usernames contain backslash \ characters? That means they are Windows accounts. The UID and PWD connection string attributes are for password-based SQL Logon accounts (accounts created within the SQL Server instance itself, not related to Windows nor Active Directory). You cannot use Windows account credentials to login to SQL Server with UID and PWD.